# How can I send a Parse Push notification only to installations that are subscribed to two channels, not either/or?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I know that according to the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-channels/JavaScript), if I wanted to send a push notification to all installations in the "Giants" and "Mets" channels, I would do it like so:

```
Parse.Push.send({
  channels: [ "Giants", "Mets" ],
  data: {
    alert: "The Giants won against the Mets 2-3."
  }
}, {
  success: function() {
    // Push was successful
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // Handle error
  }
});
```

What I want to do however, is send a push notification to only the installations that are in BOTH channels, not one of them only.

So going off the example above, rather than sending it to any installation in the "Giants" or "Mets" channels, I would only send it to installations that are in both at the same time, not ones that have only "Giants" or only "Mets". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: check for the other channel subscription in the event handler. send on only one channel, by definition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative to sending a channels based push, is to push-to-query.  You construct a Parse.Query matching the installations you want, and send that way.

Because of this, you can use the 'containsAll' constraint on the channel key.  Give this a shot.

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.containsAll("channels", ["Giants", "Mets"]);

Parse.Push.send({
  where: query,
  data: {
    alert: "The Mets Won!"
  }
}).then(function() {
  // success
}, function(error) {
  // error
});
```